# Powershellscript stops after disconnection to VM

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, screen

I would like to run a powershell script permanently on a virtual machine. In doing so, mouse movements and keystrokes. Attached are two examples:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(829 , 556)
[W.U32]::mouse_event(6,0,0,0,0);
Sleep -seconds 5
$wshellkeys.SendKeys("$global:Benutzer");
```

Unfortunately the code is paused when I disconnect the RemoteDesktop connection to the VM. As long as the connection is established, it runs without problems. I have also tried to convert it into an exe and vbs. Without success. Do you have any tips on how I can work around this problem?
Would a ghost screen be a solution?

No, unfortunately I have no influence on the settings of the VM (Enterprise managed). And I always terminate the connection by clicking on the cross.

Many thanks for your tips

Comment: What are you [actually](https://xyproblem.info/) trying to achieve? Prevent session inactivity logoff? Generating randomness by mouse movement?

Comment: No, the screen lock is not to be undone. The script opens various programmes and presses various buttons via the commands. This should also be done when I am not connected. Unfortunately, it then always stops the execution.

Comment: Please add tag for kind of VM (e. g. Hyper-V) you are using. Try to remotely launch the script through `Invoke-Command`, without opening a RDP session.  This way there is no change in RDP connection state, which could interfere with the script.